# What is the run-time of the bin packing approximation algorithm?

Tags: approximation-algorithms, time-complexity

The best approximation algorithm that I found for the bin packing problem is by [Hoberg and Rothvoss (SODA, 2017)](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1.9781611974782.172). In their Theorem 1.2, they mention that their algorithm finds a solution with at most $OPT + \log(OPT)$ bins,  and its expected run-time is polynomial in the total number of items. However, I could not understand from the paper, what is the exact polynomial? That is:  if there are $n$ items with different sizes, what is a number $k$ such that the run-time is in $O(n^k)$?

Comment: You should check with the authors. Many papers in approximation algorithms rely on various LP solving techniques and the focus is not in the running time. A random person on this forum is unlikely to know (or care) if the authors themselves did not provide a clean bound or tried to.

Comment: I asked the authors, and indeed, they confirmed that they did not try to compute an exact upper bound on the run-time.

Answer (score -2):

According to the definition of polynomial (from Introduction to the Theory of Computation. Course Technology Inc. ISBN 0-619-21764-2.):

> An algorithm is said to be of polynomial time if its running time is
> upper bounded by a polynomial expression in the size of the input for
> the algorithm, i.e., T(n) = O(n^k) for some positive constant k.

In their Theorem 1.2 they say *"The algorithm is randomized and the expected running time is polynomial"*. So their are meaning that the algorithm proposed is randomized (non deterministic), but its running time is polynomial, since is within a sum over the bins.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP knows perfectly well what “polynomial” means. They are asking for the value of the exponent, which is not clear from the paper.